# Access Variables from Controller to the Next

Tags: ruby-on-rails, controller

I have an Advertisers controller and an Experiments controller. The assocaitions are as follows

```
class Advertiser < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :experiments
 end

class Experiment < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :advertiser
 end
```

When I create an experiment the advertisers_id is passed to it and everything seems to work fine. How can I get access to the experiments (for a particular advertiser) within the advertisers show page?

So if I am on `http://localhost:3000/advertisers/5/` I would like to display a list of experiments for the advertiser with an id of `5`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you need to do is to create a nested resource, take a look here: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#nested-resources.

Your routes will be:

```
resources :advertisers do
   resources :experiments
end
```

And you can access the experiments for the given advertiser with the following route: http://localhost:3000/advertisers/5/experiments
And in that route you have to fetch the experiments for the given advertiser so you have to return:

```
Advertiser.find(params[:id]).experiments
```

Comment: I had the nested resources setup. Not sure if this is the best way, but in my Advertisers controller I added the following private action. 
`def find_experiments  @advertiser = Advertiser.find(params[:id]).experiments  end` Then I call a before_action :find_experiments

Just not sure how to fetch the experiments.

Comment: Crap, I spoke too soon. 

I have this within my advertisers show.html.erb 

`<% @advertiser.experiments.each do |experiments| %>`
`<%= @advertiser.experiments.name %>`
`<% end %>`

However, it just spits out **#<Experiment::ActiveRecord_Associations_CollectionProxy:0x8920c50> **

I cant access experiments.experiment_type or any of the other values

Comment: If I change `<%= @advertiser.experiments %>` to `<%= @advertiser.experiments.count %>` I get an accurate count of the experiments for the particular advertiser. Why can I not access the other values within experiment?

Also, i am actually trying to access the experiments within http://localhost:3000/advertisers/5/ and not http://localhost:3000/advertisers/5/experiments

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions? Been trying different things with no luck